# An urn contains 20 balls numbered 1 through 20. What is the probability that the ball numbered $18$ is the largest of three selected numbers?

Tags: probability, random-variables

An urn contains $20$ balls numbered $1$ through $20$. Three of the balls are selected from the run randomly without replacement, and $X$ denotes the largest number selected. **What is $P(X=18)$?**

This is the method I tried however, it is incorrect, I believe that this captures the chance of selecting a specific ball?
$$1- {{19\choose 3}\over{20\choose 3}} = 0.15$$

Should I maybe consider?
$$\frac{{18\choose 3} - {17\choose 3}}{20\choose3}$$

Comment: It's really hard to understand this.  You can format ${19\choose3}$ as `${19\choose3}$`

Comment: Thank you, I will update it!

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Very much appreaciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are ${20\choose3}$ ways of choosing $3$ balls.  In order that the greatest is $18$ you must choose $18$ and $2$ other balls from those numbered $1$ through $17$.  The probability is $${{17\choose2}\over{20\choose3}}$$

Comment: Thank you, I was considering that but thought it would have been wrong.

Comment: @LiborZachoval In fact $\binom{18}{3}=\binom{17}3+\binom{17}2$ by one of the identities of binomial coefficients, so this answer is equivalent to your second attempt. Both are correct.

Answer (score 7):

If it is more recognizable for you then you could think of a bag of $20$ marbles of which $17$ have color green, $1$ has color red and $2$ have color blue. If you pick $3$ marbles, then what is the probability of picking $2$ green marbles and $1$ red marble?

Answer:$$\frac{\binom{17}2\binom11\binom20}{\binom{20}3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the probability directly.

The probability of the first marble being $18$ is $\frac1{20}$.

The probability of the second marble being less than $18$ is $\frac{17}{19}$. (Note that it is without replacement, so the total number of marbles decreased from $20$ to $19$.)

The probability of the third marble being less than $18$ is $\frac{16}{18}$.

Now there are $3$ ways the number $18$ can occur: first, second or third.

Thus:
$$3\cdot \frac1{20}\cdot \frac{17}{19}\cdot \frac{16}{18}=0.119.$$

Comment: I wanted to attempt it this way, but I forgot to multiply by 3...